# Migrating on-premise TFS 2012 to VSO with free opshub tool

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are moving from on-premise tfs 2012 to the visual studio online environment.
For this we need to move a lot of projects, most of them aren’t a problem with the free opshub tool.

But 2 of our projects are really big and the tool would take about 8~9 days to complete the migration, which is too long for us.

What I would like is the following:

- Start the migration from on-premise to vso
- Keep working in the on-premise
- After the migration has finished, migrating the commits that were made in the last 8~9 days.

I’m not sure the free opshub tool supports something like this.
Is there a way to do this with the free tool? If so how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is feasible. You just start the migration initially, as your initial run is completed, and the status of migration goes to not running, you go the View Progress page, and start the already configured migration.

This will pick the newly added changes, that were done to the on-premise instance, after the actual migration started.

**Note**: You will get a process vs total revision count mismatch in status page in such cases, as total count is not calculated only once at start of the migration.

Comment: I don't see that you can restart this with the free version. I have a migration that completed yesterday that I cannot restart. The view migrations page says I need a premium license if I try to start. View migration has no start option.  The poster said they were using the free tool. Is this  a premium only feature?

Comment: OVSMU was revamped as Free and Commercial variant utility quite recently. The resume migration option which was initially available for all, is now a Premium Only feature.